# Commercial redistribution of Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, commercial

How can I get a definitive answer on the use of a customized version of Ubuntu server for redistribution with commercial software component added?

I understand that paying attention so that the use of "main" packages which are not on restricted licenses should allow redistribution and that removal of branding elements which are trademark for Ubuntu should remove such problems. However when it comes to the redistributed systems use of apt for updates, the system is in effect still a Ubuntu system.

Will this have any legal implication on distribution as all redistributed disks will still be using the bandwidth and servers of Ubuntu for updates, it seems like stealing bandwidth and server resources to me.

Any information would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

For a *definite* answer you should contact the sales team of Canonical, the company behind Ubuntu (I guess https://forms.canonical.com/sales/ is a good starting point). There are many other organizations that are concerned with the legal details around Free Software / Open Source licenses, foremost, the [Electronic Frontier Foundation](https://www.eff.org/). I doubt, however, that the EFF will offer free legal counsel in such a case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Free is not always as Free as you would think.